# How to update a table in PostgreSQL recursively based on condition in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a PostgreSQL database with many different tables and relations. There is one table named User. In our project, when people join the product, they can optionally provide FirstName and LastName. In the User table, it is kept under one column "name", so it looks like this: "Alex Smith"(exactly one space between them). There was a little bug, that if a user would not provide a FirstName or LastName, JavaScript would've inserted undefined. Our base looks like this: [image]

If there is no FirstName, it is "undefined LastName", or the other way, or "undefined undefined". Now the bug is solved, but the base needs to be cleaned up a little bit. There are thousands of users with undefined FirstNames or LastNames or both. What I was trying to do, is to write a PostgreSQL query, which goes recursively over the table User and checks if there is "undefined" in a column and replaces undefined with an empty string "".

My problem is that I need to check and replace only undefined, if there is "undefined Smith", only undefined should be replaced with an empty string. I've checked the official documentation, and in StackOverflow, I couldn't find any similar case. If anybody will have a clue, would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '\s*undefined\s*', '', 'g')`.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Postgres [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) Trim and Replace.
Using them together is what you are looking for. Something like (see [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e417b658f73585d7545aa6861bb622b6))

```
update user 
  set name = trim(replace(name, 'undefined',''));
```

***Warning:*** `USER` is a very bad table name; it is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) by by both Postgres and SQL Standard. While you can get away with using it in other than a predefined meaning, Postgres developers would be well `within their writes to make in an invalid name at any time`. **Never use reserved words nor data types as DB object names.**

Comment: `... where name like '%undefined%'` would to prevent rewriting the whole table.

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't expect this could be done so easily.

Comment: If the answer solved you issue please accept it. This helps future questioners having the same issue. Please do not leave open successfully answered questions.  @Abelisto you are correct that would be better.